# Outlook REST API - Send As

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi

I am currently using the Outlook REST API to send email. This is working fine when sending from a user mailbox such as:

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/user@domain.com/sendMail

'user@domain.com' is the UPN of a valid user account in Azure AD.

What I need to do is 'send as' a shared mailbox. According to the documentation this can be achieved by changing the 'From' property in the JSON request body. An example would be:

```js
{
  "Message": {
    "Subject": "Email Unit Test",
    "Body": {
      "ContentType": "HTML",
      "Content": "Message body"
    },
    "ToRecipients": [
      {
        "EmailAddress": {
          "Address": "recipient@somehost.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Attachments": [
    ],
    "From": {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "shared_mailbox@domain.com"
      }
    },
    "Sender": {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user@domain.com"
      }
    }
  },
  "SaveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

Now, when I give user@domain.com 'Send As' and 'Send On Behalf Of' access to the shared mailbox this works. The recipient gets an email with the from field saying **'user@domain.com On Behalf Of shared_mailbox@domain.com'**. What I want however is for the email to appear as being sent from shared_mailbox only without the on behalf of user. To test this out further I removed the 'Send On Behalf Of' access and left 'Send As' access only. In the API I now get an error:

```js
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorSendAsDenied",
        "message": "The user account which was used to submit this request does not have the right to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account., Cannot submit message."
    }
}
```

Interestingly though, in my Outlook client I can still send an email from the shared mailbox and it works as expected with no 'on behalf of' in the From field. I'm starting to wonder whether this is a limitation of the REST API however there is nothing in the Microsoft docs to suggest this.

Has anyone had similar experiences with the REST API?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same thing and it seems the REST API allows you to implement "send on behalf of" but not "send as" feature.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Victor. This is the conclusion I have come to also after exhaustive testing.

Comment: Do you know if this is still the case. If so did you find a way to implement this feature ?